# Given an array of records, how can I get an array representing a field from each one?

Tags: arrays, delphi, delphi-2010, record, projection

I have to translate some Fortran 90 code and found an interesting language feature.

As an example, they define the following type and dynamic-array variable:

```
TYPE WallInfo
  CHARACTER(len=40) :: Name
  REAL              :: Azimuth
  REAL              :: Tilt
  REAL              :: Area
  REAL              :: Height
END TYPE WallInfo

TYPE(WallInfo), ALLOCATABLE, DIMENSION(:) :: Wall
```

Later in the code, they call a function:

```
CALL HeatFlow(Wall%Area, Wall%Azimuth)
```

As a Delphi programmer, this threw me a bit because Wall is an array of records!

From the usage in the routine, it is clear that Fortran can project fields from the record array as an array of their own.

```
SUBROUTINE HeatFlow( Area, Azimuth )
  REAL, INTENT(IN), DIMENSION(:) :: Area
  REAL, INTENT(IN), DIMENSION(:) :: Azimuth
```

Does anyone know if there is a way to do this with Delphi (I'm using version 2010)?

I could write a function to extract a record value as an array but this is a bit tedious because I will have to write a dedicated routine for every field (and there are a quite a few).

I'm hoping that there is some language feature in Delphi 2010 that I have missed.

Comment: Did you try with array or record in your case array of WallInfo? Delphi support dinamic arrays. Before you enter new value first set the size of array wih SetLength.

Comment: As cool as Remy's RTTI answer is, I'd be tempted to translate the record type above into separate linear arrays: 'Name:Array of String;  Azimuth:Array of Double; ...' and then I wouldn't have to collect up the data using this lovely RTTI hack because it would already be gathered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using Extended RTTI, it is possible to create a generic function that takes the array and a field name as input and uses the array's RTTI to extract just the values of that field and create a new array with them, with the correct data type.

The following code works for me in XE2:

```
uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Rtti;

type
  FieldArray<TArrElemType, TFieldType> = class
  public
    class function Extract(const Arr: TArray<TArrElemType>; const FieldName: String): TArray<TFieldType>;
  end;

class function FieldArray<TArrElemType, TFieldType>.Extract(const Arr: TArray<TArrElemType>; const FieldName: String): TArray<TFieldType>;
var
  Ctx: TRttiContext;
  LArrElemType: TRttiType;
  LField: TRttiField;
  LFieldType: TRttiType;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Ctx := TRttiContext.Create;
  try
    LArrElemType := Ctx.GetType(TypeInfo(TArrElemType));
    LField := LArrElemType.GetField(FieldName);
    LFieldType := Ctx.GetType(TypeInfo(TFieldType));
    if LField.FieldType <> LFieldType then
      raise Exception.Create('Type mismatch');
    SetLength(Result, Length(Arr));
    for I := 0 to Length(Arr)-1 do
    begin
      Result[I] := LField.GetValue(@Arr[I]).AsType<TFieldType>;
    end;
  finally
    Ctx.Free;
  end;
end;
```

.

```
type
  WallInfo = record
    Name: array[0..39] of Char;
    Azimuth: Real;
    Tilt: Real;
    Area: Real;
    Height: Real;
  end;

procedure HeatFlow(const Area: TArray<Real>; const Azimuth: TArray<Real>);
begin
  // Area contains (4, 9) an Azimuth contains (2, 7) as expected ...
end;

var
  Wall: TArray<WallInfo>;
begin
  SetLength(Wall, 2);

  Wall[0].Name := '1';
  Wall[0].Azimuth := 2;
  Wall[0].Tilt := 3;
  Wall[0].Area := 4;
  Wall[0].Height := 5;

  Wall[1].Name := '6';
  Wall[1].Azimuth := 7;
  Wall[1].Tilt := 8;
  Wall[1].Area := 9;
  Wall[1].Height := 10;

  HeatFlow(
    FieldArray<WallInfo, Real>.Extract(Wall, 'Area'),
    FieldArray<WallInfo, Real>.Extract(Wall, 'Azimuth')
    );
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am going to try this method.  I'm starting to realize that direct translation is not that simple.  Fortran seems to have some nice matrix features but trying to simulate these in Delphi is not very efficient.  Instead of passing the array, I simply passed the whole wall array in a single parameter.

Comment: Remmy, I had to change the loop to for I := 0 to Length(Arr)-1 do to make it work in Delphi 2010.  I'm impressed, it does solve the problem and is pretty neat.

Comment: The code was written and tested in XE2. Are you saying that `High()` does not work on dynamic arrays in D2010? I updated my answer with that change.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: the question was about simulating an equivalent feature in Delphi, not how efficient its performance would be.

Comment: Sure, but it's pretty likely that performance will be important.

Answer (score 7):

I'm posting this as an answer because the comments are a bit too limited to phrase this.

This answer tries to explain the differences in memory layout of arrays and records in FORTRAN and Delphi and amends the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11873556/29290) by [Todd Grigsby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/549088/todd-grigsby) and the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11874993/29290) by [Remy Lebeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65863/remy-lebeau) (I upvoted both).

FORTRAN and a few other calculation centric languages stores nested arrays in [column major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order#Column-major_order). Delphi and many other languages use a [row major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order#Row-major_order).

From a memory perspective, a record is nothing else than an array of fields that:

- have a name and not an index
- might have different types

For calculation intensive operations, it can make sense to store nested arrays column major order when your algorithms favour the columns. Same for row major order. So in loops, you need to [match the order of your indexes with the order of your storage](http://blogs.uct.ac.za/blog/big-bytes/archives/2010/09/).

Given this record and array definition in FORTRAN:

```
TYPE WallInfo
  CHARACTER(len=40) :: Name
  REAL              :: Azimuth
  REAL              :: Tilt
  REAL              :: Area
  REAL              :: Height
END TYPE WallInfo

TYPE(WallInfo), ALLOCATABLE, DIMENSION(:) :: Wall
```

and the functional equivalent definition in Delphi:

```
type
  WallInfo = record
    Name: array[0..39] of Char;
    Azimuth: Real;
    Tilt: Real;
    Area: Real;
    Height: Real;
  end;

var
  Wall: array of WallInfo;
```

and an array of 3 WallInfo elements,
this is how the memory layout would look (they would all be continuous memory areas, I split them in lines to keep it readable):

in FORTRAN:

```
Name[0,0]...Name[0,39], Name[1,0]...Name[1,39], Name[2,0]...Name[2,39],
Azimuth[0], Azimuth[1], Azimuth[2],
Tilt[0], Tilt[1], Tilt[2],
Area[0], Area[1], Area[2],
Height[0], Height[1], Height[2],
```

in Delphi:

```
Name[0,0]...Name[0,39], Azimuth[0], Tilt[0], Area[0], Height[0],
Name[1,0]...Name[1,39], Azimuth[1], Tilt[1], Area[1], Height[1],
Name[2,0]...Name[2,39], Azimuth[2], Tilt[2], Area[2], Height[2],
```

So this FORTRAN call:

CALL HeatFlow(Wall%Area, Wall%Azimuth)

would just pass the pointers to the Area[0] and Azimuth[0] memory locations and length of those memory areas to the function.

In Delphi, that is not possible, so you have to

1. construct new Area and Azimuth arays
2. copy them from the info in the array of WallInfo record instance called Wall
3. send them to the function
4. if these are var parameters: copy the changes from the two arrays back to Wall

[Todd Grigsby](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11873556/29290) and [Remy Lebeau](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11874993/29290) showed the first three steps in their answer using straight Delphi code, or Delphi record RTTI.
Step 4 works in a similar way.

Both solutions use generics that were introduced in Delphi 2009.
[Until Delphi 2010, RTTI on records was very minimal](http://wiert.me/2009/08/24/answered-stackoverflow-on-parsing-a-record-of-unknown-structure-use-classes-with-published-properties-and-the-delphi-streaming-mechanism/)), so you got the right Delphi version for both answers.

Note (again): when translating your algorithms from FORTRAN to Delphi, make sure you watch for loops and other indexing in the arrays because of the column/row major change.

Comment: Jeroen, your comments about the loop indexing is appreciated. I already did stumble against this problem.  I was not aware of the difference in array orders between Delphi and Fortran.  Makes much more sense now.

Comment: I'm glad it helped getting more insight. Keep up the good questions!

Comment: I can't see anything in the question that relates to row major and col major issues. Where do they arise in the question? Question appears to me to be about Fortran facility to support projection. That will probably be implemented with a stride technique a la numpy array.

Comment: The major/minor are implicit in the question. The underlying question is how to get the projection in Delphi. In Fortran, you don't need to create your own projection because of the way memory is allocated in Fortran. The implicit projection in Fortran also gives you a references (so you can both read and write). If you want to read in Delphi, you need to project in one way. If you want to write in Delphi, you have to project both ways. My answer explains the differences between Fortran and Delphi thereby explaining why you need a bit of code to do all this in Delphi.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me at NumPy, numpy.Ravel is interesting http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.5.x/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html as are strides http://scipy-lectures.github.com/advanced/advanced_numpy/index.html#indexing-scheme-strides You might actually get a way with an array of pointers to the underlying fields to get read/write access. Might be faster under certain circumstances.

Comment: Whilst multi dimensional arrays are laid out col major, I don't think that arrays of aggregate types are arranged in the manner you describe. Can you provide evidence for what you claim?

Comment: Not soon: finishing up way too much before heading for holidays. Please remind me early March so I can dig for docs.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, no, there is no language construct or convenience method for splitting a single column from an array of records into a simple array of its own.

I would recommend something like the following:

```
function SplitColumn( RecordArray : Array of {recordtype} ) : Array of {columntype};
var
  column : array of {type};
  x : Integer;
begin
  setlength( result, high( RecordArray ) + 1 );
  for x := 0 to high( RecordArray ) do
    result[ x ] := RecordArray[ x ].{columnname};
end;
```

That's if you want to use dynamic arrays.  Personally, if you're porting this, I'd use List and List, as in:

```
type
   TWallList = class( TList<TWallInfo> );
   TDoubleList = class( TList<Double> );

function SplitColumn( WallList : TWallList; AreaList, AzimuthList : TDoubleList ); 
var
  x : Integer;
begin
  for x := 0 to RecList.Count-1 do
  begin
    AreaList.add( RecordArray[ x ].Area );
    Azimuth.add( RecordArray[ x ].Azimuth );
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Using Extended RTTI, it might be possible to create a generic function that takes the array and a field name as input and uses the array's RTTI to extract ust the values of that field and create a new array with them.

Comment: I posted an answer with a demo of Extended RTTI in action.